# How to add signing placeholder or checkbox into our webpage using DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am developing single page web application it has a agreement page which is pre written and dynamically loading to the user depending on the several other parameters,
I have added a placeholder underneath to the agreement for a sign or 'Agree' button.
Is it possible to embed a signature or a 'Agree' checkbox using DocuSign into that placeholder.

NB: I dont want to upload and keep the agreement into DocuSign,

Is it possible to use the docusign only for record user consent by providing signature placeholder or a 'Agree' checkbox?

the following image depicts what I'm planned to do.

Thanks in advance for guidance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> NB: I dont want to upload and keep the agreement into DocuSign

The way that DocuSign works, all documents must be uploaded to the DocuSign cloud before you can use them to obtain signature, so this is not possible.

You can certainly add a signature mark at the end of your document, by adding "tab" elements into your envelope.

Here is an example code:

```
    SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
    {
        AnchorString = "**signature_1**",
        AnchorUnits = "pixels",
        AnchorYOffset = "10",
        AnchorXOffset = "20",
    };
```

I do suggest you try our [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to get a working prototype code to get you going.